# DeltaSpike with JTA data sources

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cdi, jta, deltaspike

Has anyone tried to setup transactionality in Jetty using Apache's DeltaSpike? 
I have a webapp that I am trying to run in Jetty that uses CDI and has JTA data sources. My transaction manager is not being injected and it is null, therefore causing an error. I included the deltaspike jpa jar and followed the instruction in the link given below, but it is not working so far. I can see when I debug deep inside the hibernate classes, that my configuration is defaulting to a NOJTAPlatform, as if no JTA was configured.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Link to DeltaSpike configuration:

```
http://deltaspike.apache.org/jpa.html
```

My data sources as specified in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="database" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Which JTA provider are you using and how is it integrated in? As long as it's making the UserTransaction available in the standard JNDI locations everything should work okay.

Answer (score 1):

Which CDI implementation are you using in Jetty, is it configured properly ?

Make sure that generic CDI injection is working , by trying some simple injections?

Make sure you include the core delta spike dependencies  deltaspike-core-api and deltaspike-core-impl

depending on the way that you setup CDI you might also need deltaspike-cdictrl-api and a specific cdictrl api.

more info at http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration-of-deltaspike-core